# Unable to get data in form of list in django jquery

Tags: jquery, python, django

here is the script

```
var size = [];

var formdata = new FormData();

$("input[name='size']:checked").each(function() {
           size.push($(this).val());
    });

formdata.append('size[]' , size)

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            url : "{% url 'data_entry' %}",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) { 
             if(data == 'True'){
               alert('product uploaded successfully')
             } 
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
        }
    });
```

the sizes array looks like this

```
["L", "M", "S"]
```

and here is the view

```
def post(self, request , *args , **kwargs):
        sizes = request.POST.getlist('size')
        print sizes
        for size in sizes:
            Size.objects.create(product=instance , name='size' , value=size)
```

the list which i am getting is like this

```
[u'L,M,S']
```

the problem i am facing here is that i am not able iterate over sizes list ..all the sizes are coming together as one string...how do i  iterate over the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string using the `split()` method:

```
size = [u'L,M,S']
size = size[0].split(',') # [u'L', u'M', u'S']
```